# MediaWiki Extension testing

Tags: php, phpunit, mediawiki, dbunit, mediawiki-extensions

I want to write a phpunit test for a mediawiki extension.
It checks the values in the Database with the accepted values 
in an xml file.

How to write the test in PHPunit
i.e. which class to define and how to define the functions
in the extensions

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @group Broken
 * @group Internationalization
 */
class HttpTest extends MediaWikiTestCase {
    ...
```

See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:PHP_unit_testing/Writing_unit_tests